# Sequelize model doesn't return in then block

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to return results back to my controller if sequelize properly updated a row. It works in the current code, but I can only return true whether is fails or works.

I have tried a few different way that I thought may work, but everything returns undefined in the controller unless I hard code "returns true"

Controller

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const pageSection = promisify(db.pageSection);

exports.updateForm = async function (req, res) {

let result;

try {
   result = await pageSection.updateSection(req);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('** NOT GOOD **', err);
}

   return res.send(result);
}
```

Model

```
pageSection.updateSection = function (req) {

    var result;

    pageSection.update ({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        icon: req.body.icon
    }, {
        where: {
            id: req.body.id
        }
    })
    .then( updatedRow => {  
        return updatedRow; //Undefined in controller

        sendResult( updatedRow ); //Still undefined

        result = updatedRow; // Still undefined
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Page Model Error: ', err);
    })

    function sendResult ( updatedRow ) {
       if ( updatedRow ) { return true }

    } //Returns undefined

    return true; //Only thing that works

    return result; //Undefined


}
```

Answer (score 0):

(If you are using postgres)You need to add

```
returning: true,
plain: true
```

to your query right after the where clause, so that the updated rows of data are actually returned and setting `plain:true` ensures that what is returned are plain objects.

So now it would turn into:

```
pageSection.update ({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        icon: req.body.icon
    }, {
        where: {
            id: req.body.id
        },
        returning: true,
        plain: true
    })
```

the returned result is an array, so you'll need to access the second element of the returned array to get the updated rows.

Comment: I still get the same result. I should say, updatedRows does return a "1" but when returning in the "then" statement, it doesn't get passed to the controller.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify that `returing: true` is when you are using postgres. If so, you get an array where the first element is the number of rows affected, and second element are the updated rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Also, I noticed that in your then block, you are returning before your function invocation, so sendResult will never be reached

Comment: Ah yes, its not actually there... Those were examples of different methods that tried. So in the example of the sendResult function, I won't be returning until I call the function.